# Custom field implementation for picklists with multiple fields

Tags: custom-field, picklist, checkbox

I have 10 category names with 10+ items from each that a user can potentially pick (can select more than one)

Instead of creating 10 custom picklists is there a way of selecting the category name first (maybe via a checkbox) and then show all the correct items under that category - essentially showing/generating the appropriate list depending on what was selected in the original textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want dependent picklists:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_simple_app_adv_field_dependencies_try_it_out.htm